# aws s3 without header and changing extension of file from xls to .csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have question on how to upload files into aws s3 without header and changing extension of file from xls to .csv within aws?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the first few lines in the said file as header rows. You cannot just change the file format from .xls to .csv.

You would need a parser to read the .xls sheet and write .csv file. This can be best done on an EC2 instance or even Lambda.